# Add-ADGroupMember user from other Domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

This is my situation:
There are two domains: *Domain A* and *Domain B*.

*Domain A* does NOT trust *Domain B*, *Domain B* trusts *Domain A*.

Im executing my command on a computer in *Domain B*.

I try to add (in the beginning) just one user from *Domain A* to a AD group in *Domain B*.

```
PS> Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupOnDomainB -Members DomainA\User1 -Credential DomainA\User1

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'DomainA\User1' under: 'DC=SUB,DC=DomainB,DC=com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupOnDomainB -Members DomainA\User1 - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DomainA\User1:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

This is one of many attempts I made. Nothing successful. First I need to solve this, later it will be a script to load users and groups from a local csv file and of course to add the needed credential as well. I have everything in place but this part, just adding one user from *Domain A* to a *Domain B* Group is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```
$DomainA = 'DomainA'
$DomainB = 'DomainB'
$UserName = 'User1'
$GroupName = 'Group'
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity $UserName -Server $DomainA
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName -Server $DomainB
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User
```

Or:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User1 -MemberOf $Group
```

You *may* need to add `-Server $DomainB` to `Add-ADGroupMember`/`Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`.  It's not entirely clear if that's necessary, and I no longer have access to a forest with multiple domains.

Comment: Hi Bacon Bits

Many thanks for your input. It works with adding the "-credetial"

$User = Get-ADUser -Identity $UserName -Server $DomainA -Credential $DomainA\$UserName

in this case I'm adding myself from the other domain, otherwise of course the $UserName has to be different.