# How to add AD group to a user in another domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script to add group to user that were from different domain. My script as below :

```
 $User = Get-ADUser -Identity "testuser1" -Server testserver1
 $Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity "testgroup" -Server  testserver2
 add-content $logfile  "$logfileTime :: The AD User : $User"
 add-content $logfile  "$logfileTime :: The group : $Group" 


 try
 {
   $addMember = Add-ADGroupMember -identity "$Group" -Members "$User"
 }
 catch
 {
   add-content $logfile "Add Member Error : $_.Exception.Message"
 }
```

But I am getting the following error in my log file

```
2023-04-11 11:10:30 :: The AD User : CN=testuser1,OU=Test,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX
2023-04-11 11:10:30 :: The group : CN=testgroup,OU=test,DC=YYY,DC=YYY,DC=YYY
Add Member Error : Cannot find an object with identity:'CN=testuser1,OU=Test,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX' under: 'DC=YYY,DC=YYY,DC=YYY'..Exception.Message
```

If I tried my script for adding the same group to the user from same domain as where the group is locate, Its managed to add the group to the user 
 I had followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464008/add-adgroupmember-user-from-other-domain) but seem like its not working as expected

Comment: Youi need to specify the domain controller in `Add-ADGroupMember` (use the `-Server` parameter)

Comment: @Scepticalist so both -server parameter must use in the group and user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all of the PowerShell AD cmdlets, you have to use the `-Server` parameter every time you are targeting a domain other than the one that the computer is joined to.

When you use `Add-ADGroupMember`, you are adding the user to the `member` attribute of the group, which means you are modifying the group, not the user. So you have to use the `-Server` parameter with the domain of the group.

You also don't need to use quotes around the values.

And assigning the return value to `$addMember` is pointless. [It doesn't return anything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs) unless you use the `-PassThru` parameter.

Putting that all together, you can change that line to this:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User -Server  testserver2
```